# What methodology/process/tools support remote and "on the bench" development?

Tags: project-management, agile, kanban

I work for an IT services company that develops products as enablers for further services consulting. We have technical consultants/developers that need to be able to develop remotely and when back in the office "on the bench".

What methodology/process/tools support development by consultants when they are remote, or "on the bench", in particular how to support the management of the deliverables.

I have looked at DVCS systems, along with KanBan board tools, but I'd like to get opinions in the best way to handle this style of product development when it's not a traditional back room development situation.

Comment: In addition, often a development project is either client funded, and hence requirements are dependent on a client's requirements, and we also need to start and stop development depending on which consultant/developer is available to continue work on the product when "on the bench", cheers Mark

Comment: It's on the list of tools to look at, but I'm more interested in a process that these tools support. We need a lightweight method that enables discipline around specs before and after implementation, capturing of artefacts during implementation, as well as providing security for our business that we have full visibility of what was delivered. Not only are we not a traditional dev shop, but we also tend have churn in consultants as they progress through their careers in the industry, so we need something that has the lowest friction for handovers. Cheers, Mark

Comment: TFS provides all of those things. In particular the Web Access portion. Scrum and KanBan templates out of the box. Web hosted, so your clients have full visibility of what is done, whats in the current sprint, and whats still in the backlog.

Comment: In what way would TFS be a better fit for the style of dev I'm looking at than other tools, TFS may support Scrum or Kanban, but it's the process that I'm still shaky on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my TFS pitch.

Your developers/consultants need to be able to work in house, remotely or offline. That means local workspaces. TFS 2012 has that.

With the high rate of turnover, you need managers to be able to easily and quickly assign specific tasks to developers. With TFS you can create work items, break them into subtasks and easily assign them to any team member. When the developer begins working, you'll be able to see it and any check ins can be quickly associated (semi-automatically) with the subtask. So you'll know who did what task, and be able to see the exact code they implemented to accomplish it.

If you have managers maintaining the product backlog, all a developer needs to do is select one of the tasks assigned to him, get the latest from the source and start developing. Minimal overhead for him/her.

With Web Access you can see/edit your entire product backlog, get burndown charts (and other reports), see who completed what and when, assign tasks to team members, change team members, etc. All without VS installed, so no need to have a license for a manager if they don't develop.

Finally, fully integrated automated builds will allow you to ensure that consultants don't break your source. Gated check ins are great for this kind of team. The changeset is stored, and a build is ran. If the changeset would break the build, the check in is denied. You can also automate builds on the other side, post check in.

*Any file created outside of VS can be easily added to source control. Once the file is added, TFS monitors the file for changes and you can easily add the changes to a changeset. Once in source control, its fully in source control and available to everyone.*

*You never really mentioned any database requirements, but the new SSDT is awesome for declarative SQL development. So far, I've not had to write a single ALTER script, which makes me very happy.*

There is also fully integrated support for code reviews, build verification tests, automated deployments, architecture tools (with rules that can be enforced) and more. The rabbit hole goes pretty deep, but if you don't need it, none of it is forced on you.

So, the methodology I would suggest is a KanBan style set up, with managers pushing tasks rather than developers pulling them. This way you can reduce the impact of your high turnover rates without overly micromanaging your consultants. You'll be able to easily give them a task, let them accomplish it, and have complete visibility of the work they perform. I'm not sure how you gather your requirements, and how much input in the dev process your customers have, so its hard to go into more detail. TFS supports storyboards associated with work items, so you can give detailed specs to your developers. Also the Feedback Manager can facilitate in getting feedback on working software from product owners.

You could go Scrum with defined sprints, but I think a lot of the overhead of sprint reviews and sprint planning may be a waste for you, if you consultant turnover rate is high, and/or you don't need/want a lot of input from your consultants on user story breakdowns/requirements gathering.

Comment: ok, cool, thanks for the pitch, a lot of that is compelling, how well does TFS handle non uSoft Dev Env source components and artefacts (those things not developed in VStudio?), e.g. groovy, PL/SQL, COBOL, XLS with embedded VBS, shell scripts, perl, EAR/JAR and WAR? Due to these requirements for various artefact types and the fluid environment we are in, I'm keen to ensure any tool that does the SCM and deliverable management doesn't enforce process, but rather can support a process that we will need to adapt from the norm. If TFS can handle all this an more, then it's a front runner. Cheers

Comment: See the edit in italics.

Comment: ok cool, now I need to work out what sort of melange of a process we need that TFS would support, thanks for all the input, cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are several leaders in the ALM space, including VersionOne, Rally, ThoughtWorks Studios Mingle + Go + Twist, Jira Greenhopper, and others. These are all fundamentally iterative in nature, supporting Scrum+XP. There is a new crop of tools coming up that support Kanban, if that's your preference.

The key, though, is to decide what approach you plan to take. Iterative or flow?

Beyond that, if you're using a continuous integration server - whether open source like Jenkins or commercial like Go - then that combined with an SCM system (git, for instance) gives you visibility into what's been produced and the ability to distribute that work.

Back to your specific challenge, it seems to me that iterative wouldn't suit you, since you have people coming and going as they enter and leave the bench. Mingle supports this quite nicely, as do a few of the others. In fact, I'd suggest that the leading methodologies don't really lend themselves to your situation, as you will have neither iterations nor flow, most likely.

Comment: Thanks for the refs for ALM, I'll look into those more.

You are right, we will have neither iterations or flow, and to be able to get work split down to a granular enough level to allow for discrete work to be done will mean a large management overhead that we can afford in time or money. I like the feel of kanban, especially web based implementations, as well as DVCS such as git as they seem to fit in with some of the comms/control problems we have, but they are tools that need to support the process, so finding the process for them to fit into is the fun part, cheers Mark

Comment: ...we can afford... should of been ...we cannot afford...